# Wininet get sent headers

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, wininet

To get the headers received I can use `HttpQueryInfo` with `HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF`. For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: redacted"
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.facebook.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-FB-Debug, X-Loader-Length
public-key-pins-report-only: max-age=500; pin-sha256="WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18="; pin-sha256="r/mIkG3eEpVdm+u/ko/cwxzOMo1bk4TyHIlByibiA5E="; pin-sha256="q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ="; report-uri="http://reports.fb.com/hpkp/"
access-control-allow-method: OPTIONS
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: wd=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=-1484605344; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
X-FB-Debug: /OHaVJSuytlHcr5FJIHmFiJqDzXnpxG/byzwfSyKVoVEapJ7CB18C31eP/nCS26tXOIGAWFmqrswR4yA4QaJIQ==
Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2017 22:22:25 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

But how do I get the headers sent? For example:

```
POST /ajax/bz HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://www.facebook.com/
Content-Length: 610
Cookie: datr=KpR3WHnG8o9SSyjynboqoEFi; fr=0cgVuSHdECAqWqoBP..BYd5Qq.1M.AAA.0.0.BYfAc8.AWVTBVEg; _js_reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; _js_reg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F
Connection: keep-alive
```

Sorry if my post is mostly recognized as code because I know I am not clear at times and I wanted to make sure people understand I want to get the headers sent to the server not those received.

Comment: Why C tag? And I didn't understand what you asking.

Comment: What have you tried?  The question should contain code showing us what you already attempted

Comment: @Stargateur Because it's a question about wininet which is a C API?

Comment: @levengli I don't agree because all I am looking for is if it is possible to get the headers sent to the server and what function/flag I can use to do this. How can I try something if I can't even find a suitable API function/flag to use? This is not a question about logic, I am purely trying to find the proper function to use.

Comment: @immibis So why C++ tag?

Comment: @Stargateur I don't think you spend enough time looking at the question... I just need someone who is very knowledgeable with Wininet to help me as what I am doing is not commonly done.

Comment: @test  - `HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS` ?

Comment: @immibis I am using a C API with C++ it makes perfect sense to add this. + without being rude, and I may be wrong, but from looking at your profile you seem to have no experience with the WinApi why just waste my time criticizing my tags?

Comment: @RbMm do you have an MSDN source for this.

Comment: Are you asking about queries in a server or querying packets that you sent on the client side?

Comment: @test - may be i not understand question - but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385351(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @levengli I would like to get the raw headers that Wininet, the client, sent to the server.

Comment: @test It's me and not immibis who critique the tags and **Yes** I can critic because tag should reflect the subject of the question. Here you use a C API, why not, but who care about the language of this library? You are coding in C++ and want a C++ solution don't add C tag... it's like add C when you are coding in python because it is implemented in C... It's has nothing to do with experience of wininet but experience with SO.

Comment: Acutally @Stargateur I am looking for an language agnostic solution since I am not asking for any code. I only put those tags to find people who use the WinApi which is predominantly a C/C++ API.

Comment: @RbMm I receive `ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND` with `HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS` I perform the function call right after `HttpSendRequestW`

Comment: @RbMm you pointed me in the right direction I got it to work thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sending the request (or at least once the `INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_SENT` status event is received), you can use [`HttpQueryInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384238.aspx) specifying the `HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS/_CRLF` and `HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS` flags together.

Comment: This is the solution. It worked for me. Thanks. I got it to work with @RbMm's comment though.